# MKMapView zoom to highest zoom level

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

Ive seen a lot of examples for centering an annotation and setting the zoom.  This all works, but nothing I try sets the zoom of the map to the closest you can possibly be.  No matter what method I use, you can still pinch zoom closer after the code runs, and I need the zoom to be as close as possible after the zoom finishes.

Ive tried two methods, one works partially better than the other.

The first, the one that zooms a tad closer is this method

```
// get the annotation's point and center the map to fit it
MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1);
[self setVisibleMapRect:pointRect animated:animated];
```

adjusting the .01 values to smaller numbers has an effect to a point, but I can't reach the highest zoom.

The other method I have tried is this...

```
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, .005, .005)];
adjustedRegion.span.longitudeDelta  = 0.001;
adjustedRegion.span.latitudeDelta  = 0.001;
[self setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

Ive attempted values all the way up to .000000001 and there is no visible change in either method to get any closer at a certain point.  How can I set the maximum zoom from code?